# Why doesn't CharSequence define contains(CharSequence)?

Tags: java, design, interfaces, android

This applies to to both Java SE & Android, as the contracts are identical.

- [CharSequence documentation for Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)
- [CharSequence documentation for Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

  ---

`CharSequence` does not define a `contains(CharSequence)` method. I can't seem to find a reason why, and including it would be quite useful, preventing the need to call `CharSequence#toString()` to check for a sequence of characters.

For example, in Android, users are forced to call `Editable#toString()` to see if it contains a sequence of characters, albeit `Editable` implements `CharSequence`, which can be avoided if `CharSequence` defined `contains(CharSequence)`.

What's the idea behind this design choice? Is it a potential oversight, or is there a design reason for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point of `CharSequence` is to provide a read-only view to a character sequence, and that's it. This interface does not provide any string manipulation or searching methods. Those are out of scope.

The Interface Segregation Principle suggests that clients of a type should not depend on methods they don't use. Therefore, an interface should declare only the minimal useful set. If a different use case needs different methods, there should be a different interface.

A client that only needs a character source likely does not need search methods.

It is of course possible to overdo this Principle and end up with a thousand little interfaces. That's not good either. So the `CharSequence` interface doesn't just contain the minimal `charAt()` and `length()` methods, but also the deeply related convenience method `subSequence()`. (A CharSequence can likely provide a view onto a subsequence without a string copy, which is why this should be an instance method). Specifying `toString()` is OK because that method would be inherited anyway from `Object`. The methods `chars()` and `codePoints()` adapt a `CharSequence` to a `Stream` interface. Because these are default methods, they do not impose additional requirements for classes implementing `CharSequence`.

The `CharSequence` type is useful when a method needs a generic character source without specifying a particular implementation (e.g. String vs. CharBuffer vs. StringBuilder). The `String#join()` and `String#contains()` methods are good examples of using `CharSequence`s.

It is not necessary for `CharSequence` to provide a `contains()` method because it can be implemented externally. While Java does not have the convenience of C#'s extension methods, a static method is essentially the same thing. So instead of `boolean Editable#contains(CharSequence needle)` you would have a `static boolean contains(CharSequence haystack, CharSequence needle)`. [String search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) are a well-studied computer science topic. Different algorithms with different tradeoffs are readily available.

Further reading:

- Wikipedia: [String search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm). See particularly the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).
- Wikipedia: [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).
- Robert C. Martin: *The Interface Segregation Principle* ([PDF on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgOTViYjJhYzMtMzYxMC00MzFjLWJjMzYtOGJiMDc5N2JkYmJi/view), [PDF on the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20091103162546/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf)).

Comment: You mention "*This interface does not provide any string manipulation or searching methods. Those are out of scope.*", but `contains` is not a mutation method, and there *does* exist searching methods (`charAt`), so how does this apply?. Also, "*Because these are default methods, they do not impose additional requirements for classes implementing CharSequence.*" - Couldn't `contains` be implemented as a default via the impl `return to String().contains(...)`, removing the requirement for classes to implement?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes, `contains()` could be a default method. If it existed it should not be implemented in terms of `String#contains` but the other way round: String should use the CharSequence implementation. The `charAt()` is different. It does not implement a search algorithm, it is a crucial part of the `CharSequence`: without it, the contents couldn't be copied into a different type like `String`. Streams are a crucial part of Java8, and adding these default methods is in line with additions to other interfaces like `Collection`.